# Replace duplicate primary key rows without using Replace function

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, constraints

I have a situation where I am being passed insert statements into my table `EXAMPLE_TABLE`. I have my primary key on the column `ID` and whenever a row is inserted that has the same ID as a current value in the table, I want to replace this row.

I have no control over the function that is inserting data - it will always be an `INSERT` statement.

How could this be achieved using a constraint or trigger (or similar) instead?

Thanks all

Comment: Oracle doesn't support `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.  Are you sure you are not using MySQL?  Please tag and phrase your question correctly.

Comment: OK well I couldn't use that then anyway. I've removed the reference for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by deleting the existing row before insertion. So, you will have to use a `Trigger` that will be fired before insertion of new row. You could try the following workaround.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EXAMPLE_TABLE_TRIGGER1 
BEFORE INSERT ON EXAMPLE_TABLE 
for each row
declare
BEGIN
  delete from EXAMPLE_TABLE where id=:new.id;
END;
```

This `Trigger` will be called each time whenever new row is about to insert and it will delete the previous row so that your insert function will work properly, more precisely it will work as an `update`.